# export jqplot to pdf, using the png image generated dynamically

Tags: php, pdf, jqplot

I am using jqplot to show charts in my application. I want to export this chart in PDF. To accomplish this, I am planning to generate runtime image of the chart.
There is button in jqplot which shows image generated from jqplot using javascript. It uses following code.

```
 btn.bind('click', {chart: $(this)}, function(evt) {
                    var imgelem = evt.data.chart.jqplotToImageElem();
                    var div = $(this).nextAll('div.jqplot-image-container').first();
                    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').empty();
                    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').append(imgelem);
                    div.show(500);
                    div = null;
                });
```

I want to do it at runtime using PHP but I had no idea of how to acheive this. Help me on this.Thanks

Comment: If you have successfully accomplished the said task then could you please post the resolution for the said task?